# SQL Select from 2 tables with dominance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help to get this result in 1 sql statement?
I have 2 tables with the 2nd table having dominance over the first -- as follows:

TableA

```html
Code  |  Quantity
  1         5
  3         5
  4         5
```

TableB

```html
Code  |  Quantity
  1         5
  2         1
  4         6
```

Query Result

```html
Code  |  Quantity
  1         5   - code exists in both - return record from TableB
  2         1   - distinct only in TableB
  3         5   - distinct only in TableA
  4         6   - code exists in both - return record from TableB
```

Appreciate your help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `FULL JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.Code, t2.Code) AS Code,
       COALESCE(t2.Quantity, t1.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM TableA AS t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB AS t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
```

`COALESCE(t2.Quantity, t1.Quantity)` essentially implements your requirement for *'dominance'* of `TableB` over `TableA`: `Quantity` is picked up from `TableA` only in case there is *no matching record* in `TableB`.

For an explanation on how a `FULL JOIN` works you can have a look [**here**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> FULL OUTER JOIN, includes all rows from both tables, regardless
>   of whether or not the other table has a matching value.

Comment: Thank you so much!  So plain and simple.

Comment: @Bobbit Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.